# Appending multiple files into one

Tags: java, string, file, groovy

I have 4 different files in some locations like:
D:\1.txt
D:\2.txt
D:\3.txt and
D:\4.txt

I need to create a new file as **NewFile.txt**, It should contains all the contents present in the   above files 1.txt, 2.txt,3.txt 4.txt.......

All Data should present in the New Single file(NewFile.txt)..

Please suggest me some idea to do the same in java or Groovy....

Answer (score 10):

Here's one way to do it in Groovy:

```
// Get a writer to your new file
new File( '/tmp/newfile.txt' ).withWriter { w ->

  // For each input file path
  ['/tmp/1.txt', '/tmp/2.txt', '/tmp/3.txt'].each { f ->

    // Get a reader for the input file
    new File( f ).withReader { r ->

      // And write data from the input into the output
      w << r << '\n'
    }
  }
}
```

The advantage of doing it this way (over calling `getText` on each of the source files) is that it will not need to load the entire file into memory before writing its contents out to `newfile`.  If one of your files was immense, the other method could fail.

Comment: `File` defines `#leftShift` as well, so you could also do `src.inject(new File(dst)) { out, it -> new File(it).withInputStream { out << it } }`. I believe that'll open and close the destination file for each source file, which could be a problem if you're dealing with many small files.

Answer (score 3):

This is in groovy

```
def allContentFile = new File("D:/NewFile.txt")
def fileLocations = ['D:/1.txt' , 'D:/2.txt' , 'D:/3.txt' , 'D:/4.txt']
fileLocations.each{ allContentFile.append(new File(it).getText()) }
```

Answer (score 1):

i am showing you the way it is to be done in java:

```
public class Readdfiles {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
    String []filename={"C:\\WORK_Saurabh\\1.txt","C:\\WORK_Saurabh\\2.txt"};
    File file=new File("C:\\WORK_Saurabh\\new.txt");
    FileWriter output=new FileWriter(file);
    try
    {   
      for(int i=0;i<filename.length;i++)
      {
        BufferedReader objBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getDictionaryFilePath(filename[i])));

        String line;
        while ((line = objBufferedReader.readLine())!=null )
        {
          line=line.replace(" ","");

          output.write(line);
        }
        objBufferedReader.close();
      }
      output.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      throw new Exception (e);
    }
  }

  public static String getDictionaryFilePath(String filename) throws Exception
  {
    String dictionaryFolderPath = null;
    File configFolder = new File(filename);
    try 
    {
      dictionaryFolderPath = configFolder.getAbsolutePath();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      throw new Exception (e);
    }
    return dictionaryFolderPath;
  }
}
```

tell me if you have any doubts

Comment: Why do you catch the exception, to then throw it again wrapped as a new (more generalised) Exception?  Also, if an exception is thrown, couldn't this leave open file-handles (if the code was taken and put into a generalized function)?

Comment: actually this was part of a bigger project which i had implemented . i wrote a new program taking parts from the module which did this specific part.In my actual project this main function was a separate function which was being called inside another function.

Answer (score 1):

I tried solving this and i found its quite easy if you copy the contents to an array and write the array to a different file

```
public class Fileread 
{

public static File read(File f,File f1) throws FileNotFoundException
{

    File file3=new File("C:\\New folder\\file3.txt");
    PrintWriter output=new PrintWriter(file3);
    ArrayList arr=new ArrayList();
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(f);
    Scanner sc1=new Scanner(f1);
    while(sc.hasNext())
    {
        arr.add(sc.next());

    }
     while(sc1.hasNext())
    {
        arr.add(sc1.next());

    }
       output.print(arr);
   output.close();

    return file3;
}
/**
 *
 * @param args
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try
    {
   File file1=new File("C:\\New folder\\file1.txt");
   File file2=new File("C:\\New folder\\file2.txt");
   File file3=read(file1,file2);
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(file3);
   while(sc.hasNext())
       System.out.print(sc.next());

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.printf("Error  :%s",e);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in Java. Hope it helps you resolve your problem:

```
import java.io.*;
class FileRead {
public void readFile(String[] args) {
for (String textfile : args) {

try{
      // Open the file that is the first 
      // command line parameter
      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(textfile);
      // Get the object of DataInputStream
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      String strLine;
      //Read File Line By Line
      while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
      // Print the content on the console
      System.out.println (strLine);

    // Write to the new file
      FileWriter filestream = new FileWriter("Combination.txt",true);
      BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filestream);
      out.write(strLine);
      //Close the output stream
      out.close();

      }
      //Close the input stream
      in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
}
}

 public static void main(String args[]) {
 FileRead myReader = new FileRead();
 String fileArray[] = {"file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "file4.txt"};
    myReader.readFile(fileArray);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner example:

```
def out = new File(".all_profiles")
['.bash_profile', '.bashrc', '.zshrc'].each {out << new File(it).text}
```

OR

```
['.bash_profile', '.bashrc', '.zshrc'].collect{new File(it)}.each{out << it.text}
```

Tim's implementation is better if you have big files.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> files=new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=10;i<14;i++)
            files.add("C://opt/Test/test"+i+".csv");

    String destFile ="C://opt/Test/test.csv";
    System.out.println("TO "+destFile);
    long st=System.currentTimeMillis();
    mergefiles(files, destFile);
    System.out.println("DONE."+(st-System.currentTimeMillis()));
}

public static void mergefiles(List<String> files,String destFile){
    Path outFile = Paths.get(destFile);
    try(FileChannel out=FileChannel.open(outFile, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
          for(String file:files) {
            Path inFile=Paths.get(file);
            System.out.println(inFile);
            try(FileChannel in=FileChannel.open(inFile, StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
              for(long p=0, l=in.size(); p<l; )
                p+=in.transferTo(p, l-p, out);
            }catch (IOException e) {
                 System.out.println("ERROR:: "+e.getMessage());
            }
            out.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("\n".getBytes()));
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println("ERROR:: "+e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The answer is code only? Can you edit with an explanation please.  [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.