# Is it possible to merge two text files without reading lines, using java?

Tags: java, text-files, out-of-memory, overhead, read-write

I am in a situation where I need to join a few very large text files, using a java program.

Eg:

file_01

```
line 01
line 02
line 03
```

file_02

```
line 04
line 05
line 06
```

file_03

```
line 07
line 08
line 09
```

The output file needs to be like,

```
line 01
line 02
line 03
line 04
line 05
line 06
line 07
line 08
line 09
```

Is it possible to do this without reading every single line of each file?

Comment: show your efforts, please. Try 'cat file1 file2 file2 |sort '

Comment: I see out-of-memory as a tag. What kind of problem did you have?

Comment: Check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065865/appending-multiple-files-into-one

Comment: Actually,my program has a part of file type conversion as well.There,I did a few things to reduce time consumption.While doing file reading/writing,I faced a few memory issues as well,since my files were such huge ones.I managed to minimize the IO operations,with the use of stringbuilders and managed to maximize the performance.I used a few threads to process the file as parts.However,this is related to what I'm going to do in the next step,which is merging those parts together.I worry whether my program would run out of memory if I read all the lines within.just looked for a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to merge two files without reading all the contents (of at lest one of them) and writing it into another file. Filesystems don't support that operation. If you need to merge two files you read them one by one (not necessary a line at a time, but all the contents) and write it into another single file.

**Edit Example:**

```
 BufferedReader br(in);
 String line;

 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      // write it out
 }
```

Comment: The source text files that I suppose to use are very large files (approximately 1.7 GB each). Is it possible to append one file to another, without using a buffered reader and using a for loop to write the lines? Is there any mechanism so that I could refer the two files, and instruct the second one to be appended to the fist one in a Streaming manner?

Comment: `BufferedReader` is streaming by default. Once you have read from it the data in the `Reader` Object is discarded. Check my little example snippet. Optionally the second initialization parameter sets the buffer size, default is usually one or two pages.