# How do I concatenate multiple files in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

Is there an easy way to concatenate multiple text files into a single one in Gradle? The build script should look something like this:

```
FileCollection jsDeps = files(
   'file1.js',
   'file2.js'
   // other files here
)

task concatenate << {
   // concatenate the files to file.js
}
```

I am using Gradle 2.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(new File('test.js')).text = file('test1.js').getText() + file('test2.js').getText()
```

**UPDATE:**

For collections.

```
(new File('test.js')).text = files('test1.js', 'test2.js').collect{it.getText()}.join("\n")
```

Comment: What if collection of files is not fixed?

Comment: Ok. You are right. Maybe I missunderstood the problem. Is the question how to loop the files or how to concatenate?

Comment: OP didn't clarify it properly, however you can provide a solution that will concatenate a collection of files.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that the collection can be arbitrary. Edited the question.

Answer (score 9):

leftShift / "<<" is deprecated in gradle 3.4 You may use something like:

```
task concatenate {
    doLast {
        def toConcatenate = files("filename1", "filename2", ...)
        def outputFileName = "output.txt"
        def output = new File(outputFileName)
        output.write('') // truncate output if needed
        toConcatenate.each { f -> output << f.text }
    }
```

Comment: It replaces utf-8 characters with a question mark in Gradle 5.6.4

Comment: To get all files dynamically from the folder instead of hardcoding file name, def toConcatenate = fileTree("sourceDir")

Answer (score 6):

You can also register the files as inputs/outputs to help with incremental builds. It's especially helpful with larger files.

something like this:

```
task 'concatenateFiles', {
    inputs.files( fileTree( "path/to/dir/with/files" ) ).skipWhenEmpty()
    outputs.file( "$project.buildDir/tmp/concatinated.js" )
    doLast {
        outputs.files.singleFile.withOutputStream { out ->
            for ( file in inputs.files ) file.withInputStream { out << it << '\n' }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of the fileTree, it can also be replaced with sourceset/sourceset output, specific files, outputs from a different task, etc.

[Gradle doc on task inputs/output](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html)

[Concatenating files in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13066279/5130921)

Answer (score 5):

The following task should do the job:

```
task concatenate << {
    def toConcatenate = files('f1', 'f2', 'f3')
    def output = new File('output')
    toConcatenate.each { f -> output << f.text }
}
```

Comment: will append to existing file. Might want to delete file first.