# How can I concatenate text files in fat jar with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, concatenation, executable-jar

I'm building a fat jar with the code below. However, I have multiple property files with the same name in different jars, which are collected into the fat jar.

I guess the solution is to concatenate/merge the files with the same name into one file, but how do I do it? I found this question [How do I concatenate multiple files in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692641/how-do-i-concatenate-multiple-files-in-gradle).

How can I access and merge the property files (let's name them myproperties.properties) in the `it` objects?

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
 def mainClass = "myclass"
 def jarName = "myjarname"
    zip64=true
    manifest {
      attributes(
        'Main-Class': mainClass,
        'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
      )
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-' + jarName + '-all'
    from { 
      configurations.compile.collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) 
      } 
    }
    {
      exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
    }
    with jar
 }
```

---

**Solution:**
I marked the given answer as the solution although I haven't tried it. Instead we solved the problem by creating multiple jars and adding those to the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you could write a custom `MergeCopy` task. Eg

```
public interface FileMerger implements Serializable {
    public void merge(String path, List<File> files, OutputStream out) throws IOException;
}

public class MergeCopy extends DefaultTask {
    private File outputDir;
    private List<FileTree> fileTrees = []

    @TaskInput
    FileMerger merger

    @OutputDirectory
    File getOutputDir() {
       return outputDir
    }

    @InputFiles
    List<FileTree> getFileTrees() {
       return fileTrees
    }

    void from(FileTree fileTree) {
        fileTrees.add(fileTree)
    }

    void into(Object into) {
        outputDir = project.file(into)
    }

    @TaskAction
    void copyAndMerge() {
       Map<String, List<File>> fileMap = [:]
       FileTree allTree = project.files().asFileTree
       fileTrees.each { FileTree fileTree ->
           allTree = allTree.plus(fileTree)
           fileTree.visit { FileVisitDetails fvd ->
               String path = fvd.path.path
               List<File> matches = fileMap[path] ?: []
               matches << fvd.file
               fileMap[path] = matches
           }
       }
       Set<String> dupPaths = [] as Set
       Set<String> nonDupPaths = [] as Set
       fileMap.each { String path, List<File> matches ->
           if (matches.size() > 1) {
              dupPaths << path
           } else {
              nonDupPaths << path
           }
       }
       FileTree nonDups = allTree.matching {
           exclude dupPaths
       }
       project.copy {
           from nonDups
           into outputDir
       }
       for (String dupPath : dupPaths) {
           List<File> matches = fileMap[dupPath]
           File outFile = new File(outputDir, dupPath)
           outFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
           try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile)) {
               merger.merge(dupPath, matches, out)
               out.flush()
           }
       }
    }
}
```

You could then do

```
task mergeCopy(type: MergeCopy) {
    configurations.compile.files.each {
        from it.directory ? fileTree(it) : zipTree(it)
    } 
    into "$buildDir/mergeCopy"
    merger = { String path, List<File> files, OutputStream out ->
       // TODO: implement
    }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn mergeCopy
    from mergeCopy.outputDir
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried adding the classes to my build.gradle, but I get an error: unexpected token: Action @ line 78, column 25.             fileTree.visit((Action<? super FileVisitDetails> visitor). I'm using Gradle 4.2.1.

Comment: I've totally rewritten the solution to use a task with up-to-date checking. Try again

Comment: So, did this work? Keep in mind that you can move `FileMerger` and `MergeCopy` sources to `buildSrc/src/main/groovy` to keep the `build.gradle` clean

Comment: I can't reassure it, since we strived for a different approach to the problem altogether. However, I don't have the time, to test your solution either.