# No query executer factory registered for the 'sql' language

Tags: java, jasper-reports

The issue regarding the error: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No query executer factory registered for the 'sql' language

My issue is: whenever I try to run JasperReports from dev environment I can get the reports generated. But when I run jar file the error comes up.

Is there any workaround to set the enironment variable net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory.sql ? I try to use Jasper 6.19.1 and 6.20.0 but the problem us the same.

The problem is related to this variable located in the file default.jasperreports.properties that's located in the JasperReports jar root.

I'm using IntelliJ Ide and gradle

I created a program to show the problem. There are only two files.

Main.java

```
package br.com.mawan.mawanReport;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

public class Main {

    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wavecounter";
    private static final String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String login = "root";
    private static final String pwd = "";

    public Main() {}

    public void print(String path ) throws JRException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, pwd);
        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport( path );
        JasperPrint reportFill = JasperFillManager.fillReport( report , null, conn );
        JasperViewer.viewReport( reportFill , true );
        conn.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new br.com.mawan.mawanReport.Main().print( "C:\\wavecounter\\reports\\Teste.jrxml" );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'br.com.mawan'
version '1.0.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.2")
    implementation("com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7")
    implementation("org.olap4j:olap4j:1.2.0")
    implementation("net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:5.6.1")
    implementation("net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-fonts:5.6.1")
    implementation("xerces:xercesImpl:2.10.0")
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.29")
}

jar {
    manifest { attributes "Main-Class": "br.com.mawan.mawanReport.Main" }
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

Comment: Both jasperreports and jasperreports-fonts include a resource called jasperreports_extension.properties, and with your gradle task the resource from the second jar overwrites the first one.  You need to append the resources as done [here with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35025718/983559), but I don't know how easy it is to do that with Gradle (probably [not easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47155705/983559)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it I created a file concatenating both files and put it in the **resource** with the name *new.jasperreports_extension.properties*.

Inside the jar tag I inserted the file name in **exclude** command. After that a insert a command to rename *new.jasperreports_extension.properties* to *jasperreports_extension.properties*.

```
jar {
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA','jasperreports_extension.properties'
    manifest { attributes "Main-Class": "br.com.mawan.mawanReport.Main" }
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    rename('new.jasperreports_extension.properties', "jasperreports_extension.properties")
}
```

After that everything worked.

I would like to give credit to dada67.